# Embedded videos with videoJS - size issue with Safari

Tags: css, html, video, safari

Ok I have got something working perfectly with Chrome, but in Safari it's a bit weird.

The first video plays fine, exactly how I want it to, but a bit further down the page I have another embedded video, and even though I am using the exact same code for each one, except for 'autoplay' and the video file of course, the second one is really big, seems to be double the height..

It's like it's adding on 100% each time.

this is the html for the 1st one

```
<video autoplay id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
preload="auto" poster="../images/posters/1969.png"
data-setup="{}"> 
<source src="../videos/1969.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<source src="../videos/1969.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>
```

and the second one

```
<video id="anothervideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
preload="auto" poster="../images/posters/1969.png"
data-setup="{}"> 
<source src="../videos/video-2.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<source src="../videos/video-2.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>
```

thought it might be using the same id for both that was causing the problem, so used two separate ones, but didnt do anything, here's the css for the ids

```
min-height: 100%; min-width: 100%; height: auto !important; width: auto !important;
```

No idea what is going on!

Comment: Do you have a working example of this that you can link to?

Comment: http://www.oreardon.com/test/1969/index.html - hasnt got the videos on there, but you see what i mean, I've also been playing about with a few things, so it's changed a bit, its even bigger now!

Comment: Every section (block) on that page appears to look fine to me.  I"m on Chrome Dev: Mac.  Each section is as tall and wide as the window and none of them appear to be bigger or smaller than they need to be.  So were you able to solve it or is it still happening?  What browser are you using?

Comment: Nah as I say Chrome is perfect, just in Safari, the player for the second video is huge..!

Answer (score 0):

I missed that part about it being in Safari.  But I do have a solution for you.  So it does appear to be the min-height causing issues.  What you can do is add this CSS:

```
#my_video_2{
    min-height:inherit;
}
```

It appears that having that on the second video caused issues, but it is needed for the first video to display properly.

See if that works.

Comment: that has made it disappear all together, unless I am doing something wrong, I have updated that link ^^

Edit: well its there, but has 0px height

Comment: I keep on getting it to come up right on load using max-height: 100%; but as soon as you press the play button, the video just disappears. Frustrating!

Comment: You'll have to keep playing around with it.  You're making big changes to the CSS (which is good for testing) but I can't keep up with what you're doing currently with what was working before.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your help anyway. Not going to let this beat me.